# Getting garbage value in structure when reading from file

Tags: c, linux, file, parsing, struct

I have a text file like this

```
987jgkfl
12358ldjkdju
7579jngj
8uuujkl
09698fjfj
```

I have a structure like this

```
struct emprec

{

    int empid;
    int todo;
    char name[20];

};
```

I write the values of the struct into file like this

```
fd = fopen("/home/tarun/Desktop/test34.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fd,"%d",temp2.empid);
    fprintf(fd,"%s",temp2.name);
    count++;
    fclose(fd);
```

But when i read from the file i am getting the garbage value

```
while(i<=count)
{
fread(&temp5,sizeof(temp5),1,fd);
//fscanf(fd,"%d,%s",&temp5.empid,temp5.name);
//int k = strlen(temp5.name);
//printf("Value of k is %d\n",k);
//temp5.name[7]= '\0';
//fread(&temp5.empid,sizeof(temp5.empid),1,fd);
//fread(temp5.name,20,1,fd);
printf("\n%d %s",temp5.empid,temp5.name);
i++;
}
fclose(fd);
```

Please tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: try formatted reading... like  `fscanf()`.

Comment: also, what is the purpose of the very first file?

Comment: @SouravGhosh First file is the text file from where i have to read the values. and also tryed fscanf but not getting the exact output

Comment: i am not sure but perhaps a `rewind(fp);` is required before `fread`.

Comment: You're writing a textual representation (with fptrinf) of your struct but attempting to read a binary representation (with fread).

Answer (score 2):

Like say nemetroid :

> You're writing a textual representation (with
>   fptrinf) of your struct but attempting to read a binary representation
>   (with fread).

For example, suppose you want write an int in a file. By doing like this :

```
   fd = fopen("file","a+");
   fprintf(fd,"%d",42);
```

You will write the character '4' and the character '2'. In ASCII, '4' is 0x34 and '2' is 0x32. 
If you want to read that file and try to put it in an 4 bytes integer by doing like this :

```
int a = 0;
fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fd);
```

The variable 'a' will contain the data on the file :

```
a = 0x00003234
```

And not 42 (0x0000002a) as you expect.

Comment: Yes, I make an error by saying a = 0x3442 instead of 0x3432 (and I've forgotten the endianness). Step by step with GDB show me that a=0x3234.

Comment: Nice ,using debugger .

Answer (score 0):

There were some calls that was missing from your code:

1. `fflush()`

   - Used to flush the file's buffer, you have to call this if you performed writes to the file and now you want to read
2. `fseek`

   - Used to set the file position indicator. In your case, the file position indicator was at the end of the file. Use `fseek()` to set the file position to where you started writing and than start reading.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf function corresponds to fprintf. fread corresponds to fwrite. It means if you want to dump the structure using fprintf, then read it using fscanf. if you want to read the structure using fread then dump it using fwrite. Referring manpages of these functions should help.